# Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized while printing a page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, printing

I'm getting "unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized" exception while printing the page.

For printing I use string builder to append the HTML component and then put it into Literal and then literal assign to Session["ctrl"]. I uses a page name `Print.aspx` and a helper function `PrintHelper`.

```
private void PrintApplication(StudentDetails StudentData )
{
        List<StudentAttDetails> itemAtt = new List<StudentAttDetails>();
        List<StudentAcadDetails> itemAcad = new List<StudentAcadDetails>();
        itemAtt = StudentData.AttDetails;
        itemAcad = StudentData.AccDetails;

        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<div class=' peopledetails-piims'>");
            sb.Append("<table class='blueTable'>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td colspan='2' style='font-size:1em;font-weight:bold;text-align-left;'>स्कूल की जानकारी, स्थिति व जगह</td><td colspan='2' style='font-size:1.2em;font-weight:bold;text-align-right;'>आवेदन क्रमांक:" + "</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td>यूडाइस कोड:</td><td>" + StudentData.UdiseCode + "</td><td>सत्र:</td><td>" + StudentData.Session + "</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td>कक्षा: </td><td>" + StudentData.Class + "</td><td>मधायम:</td><td>" + StudentData.Medium + "</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td>आवेदन क्रमांक:  </td><td>" + StudentData.ApplicationId + "</td><td>विध्यार्थी का नाम:</td><td>" + StudentData.StudentName + "</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td>जाति </td><td>:</td><td>" + StudentData.Caste + "</td><td>जन्मतिथि </td><td>:</td><td>" + StudentData.DOB + "</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td>अभिभावक का नाम </td><td>:</td><td>" + StudentData.ParentsName + "</td><td>घर का पता </td><td>:</td><td>" + StudentData.Address + "</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td>दाखिले का वर्ष </td><td>:</td><td>" + StudentData.YearOfJoin + "</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("</table>");

            //sb.Append("</br>");
            //sb.Append("</br>");

            sb.Append("<table class='blueTable'>");
            sb.Append("<thead>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td colspan='3' style='font-size:1em;font-weight:bold;text-align: center;'>उपस्थिति की जानकारी</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("</thead>");
            sb.Append("<thead>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<th>SNo</th><th>वर्ष</th><th>बच्चे की उपस्थिति</th>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("</thead>");
            sb.Append("<tbody>");
            int snPreferences = 1;
            foreach (StudentAttDetails sad in itemAtt)
            {
                sb.Append("<tr>");
                sb.Append("<td>" + snPreferences.ToString() + "</td><td>" + (sad.Year).ToString() + "</td><td>" + sad.Attendance + "</td>");
                sb.Append("</tr>");
                snPreferences += 1;
            }
            sb.Append("</tbody>");
            sb.Append("</table>");

            //sb.Append("</br>");
            //sb.Append("</br>");


            sb.Append("<table class='blueTable'>");
            sb.Append("<thead>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td colspan='3' style='font-size:1em;font-weight:bold;text-align: center;'>विवरण की जानकारी</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("</thead>");
            sb.Append("<thead>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<th>SNo</th><th>वर्ष</th><th>ग्रेड</th><th>कुल बच्चो की संख्या</th><th>कक्षा मे प्राप्त श्रेणी</th>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("</thead>");
            sb.Append("<tbody>");
            int sno = 1;
            foreach (StudentAcadDetails sacd in itemAcad)
            {
                sb.Append("<tr>");
                sb.Append("<td>" + sno.ToString() + "</td><td>" + (sacd.Year).ToString() + "</td><td>" + sacd.Grade.ToString() + "</td><td>" + (sacd.TotalStudent).ToString() + "</td><td>" + (sacd.Rank).ToString() + "</td><td>");
                sb.Append("</tr>");
                sno += 1;
            }
            sb.Append("</tbody>");
            sb.Append("</table>");
            sb.Append("</div>");

            ltlPrint.Text = "";
            ltlPrint.Text = sb.ToString();

            Session["ctrl"] = null;
            #region Print Application
            Session["ctrl"] = ltlPrint;
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "onclick", "<script language=javascript>window.open('../Print.aspx','PrintMe','height=700px,width=700px,scrollbars=1');</script>");
            #endregion
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
}
```

Print.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            Control ctrl = (Control)Session["ctrl"];
            PrintHelper.PrintWebControlStudentApp(ctrl);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
 }
```

I am getting an error on `Print.aspx` page where catch() throws an exception:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Page.aspx page, the thread is aborted due to some dependency of your system to the master page.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a Debug Build? Or a release Build, than for Sure the Code is optimized.

Comment: I don't Understand. Do you want to say Rebuild/Build the solution and than do debugging?

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "onclick", "<script language=javascript>window.open('../Print.aspx','PrintMe','height=700px,width=700px,scrollbars=1');</script>");
```

> Your Error--- Unable to evaluate expression because the code is
>   optimized

**Note:- I think...You getting error just because page not rediect in proper way... on the destination**

```
string url="";// In this Line you have to add url in proper way ...so you can easliy redirect 

string dim = "toolbar=0,fullscreen=1,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,maximize=0,height=1000px";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Trim(), "window.open('" + url + "', 'Popup', '" + dim + "');", true);
```

Comment: I tried the way you mention above, but getting the same error.